# Messages from Facebook Graph API without "/pageid/conversations" endpoint

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to access messages that belong to a page where I have a 'page advertiser' role. I was trying to use the Facebook Graph API/{pageid}/conversations endpoint, however it seems that I need to have an admin, editor or moderator role to get the required permission.
[image]

Assuming that I cannot change my page role, is there any other API or permission that let's me access messages that belong to a page? I know for a fact that [Chatfuel](http://chatfuel.com/) can access messages that belong to pages, but I'm not entirely sure what page role they get (perhaps they do ask for a permission to become an admin, editor or moderator of the pages that they build chatbots for).

Within the Facebook page settings admins can access subscribed apps under settings/messenger platform (where Chatfuel gets listed too), however I'm not sure how my app can request to become a subscribed app for a page that I only have an advertiser role.

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: You will have to let a page admin login to your app, grant it the necessary permissions, and then get a page access token. Then you use that token to subscribe the app to the page via an API call.